# Fit Michaelis-Menten function

Tags: r, statistics, nls

I am new to R and am trying to fit a nonlinear least squares model. The function is

```r
R=a*SSB/(1+b*SSB)
```

the variables `SSB` and `R` are columns from a data set.

The initial parameters are `a = 0.005`, `b= 3.0e-10`

Comment: could you share more information on your data and dataframe using dput?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at `?nls` already? Try

```
nls(R ~ a * SSB / (1 + b * SSB), data = YourDataSet,
    start = list(a = 0.005, b = 3e-10))
```